# Lupa can't find lua on OSX 10.11.4 El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, lua, pip, lupa

I'm following official docs to install lupa:

```
brew install lua
brew install pkg-config
pip install lupa
```

After I run that I can successfully run lua from command line from any folder. However, when running Django management commands (e.g. `python manage.py migrate`), I get following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _luaL_newstate
  Referenced from: /Users/oz/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lupa/_lupa.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _luaL_newstate
  Referenced from: /Users/oz/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lupa/_lupa.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I'm running OSX 10.11.4 El Capitan, pip 8.1.2, lupa 1.3, lua 5.2.4.

How can I make lupa work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to install lupa with LDFLAGS:

```
brew install lua
brew install pkg-config
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/bin/lua" pip install lupa --no-binary :all:
```